# trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed

Tags: windows, domain, active-directory

I had a work computer (Windows 7) set up with local login (not domain login).
Later I needed to login to the domain.

So I made changes to join the domain by right-clicking on My computer and generating a network Id and entering the domain name there. I was successfully able to join the domain.

Now I cannot log back into the local login. I get the message saying "the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed".

How do I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "generating a network Id"?

Answer (score 4):

I saw this a couple times recently - my solution, which hasn't failed yet, was to unplug the network cable and log on to the machine as an admin and then plug the network back in once I got to the desktop. Hooray for cached credentials. At that point I believe I went through the motions of rejoining the domain which found the computer's domain account and asked if I wanted to use it, which I accepted.

It was a Windows 7 client on a SBS 2003 domain, I had previously logged in as an admin to setup some software.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to disconnect from the network and use cached credentials-- that worked for me.  Unfortunately in my case the domain controller seemed to believe I was a totally different computer and made me rename the computer when re-joining the domain, but that wasn't a huge issue.

Answer (score 2):

The failed trust relationship might be due to the fact that the machine's account has been disabled or removed from the domain it has once joined. If you need to perform a logon with a local account, just use the MACHINENAME\username syntax when specifying the username.